# Posterior of factors in factor analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Based on the book by Bartholomew et al. (2011) and Equation (3.6) the posterior distribution of a factor analysis model is a multivariate normal
\begin{equation}
N_q (\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{T} (\boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{\Lambda} ^{T} + \boldsymbol{\Psi})^{-1}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu}), (\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{T}\boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}+\boldsymbol{I})^{-1} )
\end{equation}
However, using the formulas for the conditional normal distributions, the respective covariance matrix is given by
$\boldsymbol\Sigma_{11} - \boldsymbol\Sigma_{12} \boldsymbol\Sigma_{22}^{-1} \boldsymbol\Sigma_{21}$ which in this case leads to
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{I} - \boldsymbol\Lambda^{T} (\boldsymbol{\Lambda\Lambda^{T}+\Psi})^{-1} \boldsymbol\Lambda
\end{equation}
I don't understand how is this the same with the covariance matrix indicated by Eq. (3.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation relies on a result known as the matrix inversion lemma, or [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). From wikipedia:

> $$(A + UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}$$

Identifying $A = \mathbf{I}$, $U = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^T$, $C = \boldsymbol{\Psi}^{-1}$ and  $V = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ yields the expression you seek.